# Firefox - Http download using Iframe plays the video file

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

In Firefox I am using this code to download .Mp4 file from server.
but in Firefox the plugin is already set in OPTIONS/APPLICATION tab to open it in Quicktime.

So the result is the file downloads in hidden iframe and starts playing.
I want to download the file and not play the file directly.

How can I set it such that it open the save as dialog box instead of playing.
how i can control this behavior from server.

```
        var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);

        if (iframe === null) {
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        iframe.src = signedUrl;
```

Comment: Doesn't the content type header determine if a file is downloaded or not? This means you can do this by providing a content type response header on the server that triggers the browser into downloading the file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186867/what-content-type-to-force-download-of-text-response

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my Apache 2 server force a browser to open a file transfer dialogue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398223/how-do-i-make-my-apache-2-server-force-a-browser-to-open-a-file-transfer-dialogu)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`download` attribute of `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility) if you're targeting Firefox.